# Нужна запятая или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый вечер!
Такая фраза: "Однако его родители хотели, чтобы он посвятил себя учёбе, ведь как они считали, спорт негативно повлияет на успеваемость в школе".
Я считаю, что между "ведь" и "как" запятая не нужна, но мне все возражают.
Как правильно? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Однако его родители хотели, чтобы он посвятил себя учёбе, ведь, как они считали, спорт негативно повлияет на успеваемость в школе".

Как они считали - вводное предложение со значением источника информации, частица ВЕДЬ выступает в  роли союза со значением причины и относится к предложению "ведь спорт негативно повлияет на успеваемость в школе".

Comment: Спасибо, вот это убедительно! Значит, я был неправ. :)

Answer (score 3):

Вводное предложение ***"как они считали"*** должно быть обособлено.